# MySQL: Display query results in multiple columns based on value from a table

Tags: mysql

Would like to display query result from different tables:

```
    Confirmed Orders:                    Confirmed Order Details:   
    +-------+--------+-------+          +--------+------+-------+------+
    |COID   |Customer|Payment|          |   CODID| COID | Items | Qty  |
    +-------+--------+-------+          +--------+------+-------+------+
    |     1 |   Jack | 11000 |          |      A |     1| Crack |    5 |
    |     2 |   Jill |  3000 |          |      B |     2|  Weed |    7 |
    +-------+--------+-------+          |      C |     2|  Beer |    7 |
                                        +--------+------+-------+------+


    Purchase Orders:                        
    +--------+----------+---------+         
    |   POID | PO Amount| Vendor  |
    +--------+----------+---------+ 
    |      6 |      100 | Puffy.D | 
    |      7 |      500 | Bud Wise| 
    +--------+----------+---------+
```

And based on the values from a table named "DataMatrix":

```
    DataMatrix:
    +--------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+
    | DataID |             table1 | DataID2 |                   table2 |
    +--------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+
    |      1 | Confirmed Orders   |      A  | Confirmed Order Details  |
    |      6 | Purchase  Orders   |      A  | Confirmed Order Details  |
    |      6 | Purchase  Orders   |     1T  |                Tracking  |
    |      2 | Confirmed Orders   |      B  | Confirmed Order Details  |
    |      2 | Confirmed Orders   |      C  | Confirmed Order Details  |
    |      7 | Purchase  Orders   |      B  | Confirmed Order Details  |
    |      7 | Purchase  Orders   |      C  | Confirmed Order Details  |
    |      7 | Purchase  Orders   |     2T  |                Tracking  |
    |      7 | Purchase  Orders   |     3T  |                Tracking  |
    +--------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

So hoping the result will be displayed into one table, such as below:

```
    +--------+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+----------+---------+
    |   CODID| COID | Items |  Qty  |Customer|Payment|   POID | PO Amount| Vendor  |
    +--------+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+----------+---------+
    |      A |     1| Crack |     5 |   Jack | 11000 |      6 |     100  | Puffy.D 
    |      B |     2|  Weed |     7 |   Jill |  3000 |      7 |     500  | Bud Wise|
    |      C |     2|  Beer |     7 |   Jill |  3000 |      7 |     500  | Bud Wise|
    +--------+------+-------+-------+--------+-------+--------+----------+---------+
```

Self-taught MySQL, learned mostly from StackOverflow.  I tried

```
    max(case when (criteria) then...etc.
```

But the result can only be displayed in one column? Is what I am seeking even possible just using MySQL?

Comment: How is purachase related to  confirmed order/order details?

Comment: Thank you for your question!  `Purchase Order` is related to `Confirmed Order Details` from the table `DataMatrix:`.  I made a typo in `DataMatrix:` Row 2,  Column DataID2: it should be 'A', not '1'.

Comment: Given the information provided it is not possible because there is no assocciation between the Tracking and the Confirmed Order Details... you link the confirmed details to a purchase order and you link the purchase order to tracking...but its impossible to tell which tracking item is for which order item.

Comment: I see.  If I take out the Tracking column from the results, could it still be done?  Is it using `(case when (criteria) then...etc.` for each column that I want to be displayed?